# Vertical space after caption

Tags: formatting

I am writing an algorithm in the `figure` environment, and when I write caption, it does not appear decently. Rather, it appears too close to the textbox.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,emptycopyrightspace]{ewsn-proc}
\usepackage{amsmath,balance,amssymb,amsfonts,complexity,filecontents,graphicx,pgfplots,textcomp,tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[sort,nocompress]{cite}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
                \textsc{SomeAlgorithm}
                \begin{algorithmic}[1]

                    \State Do this
                    \State Do that
                    \If{You cannot do this or that}
                    \State Do something else
                    \EndIf
                    \While{You are not successful}
                    \State Work hard
                    \EndWhile
        \end{algorithmic}  \end{minipage}}

        \caption{Some algorithm}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And this is the output:
[image]

The caption is too close to the border of the figure. I tried to give some space with `\vspace{...}` but it does not work.

How can write captions such that they are a bit far away from the figure?

Comment: in article class it compiles ok without this problem. This means that your class or your class options causes this problem. Please provide a way to access somewhere your class. (Also edit your post to add the first backslash above the code at your documentcalss command)

Comment: Look into the `caption` - this lets you customise basically everything of a caption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `caption` package, which sets more decent spacing between caption and float. This being said, I don't see why you don't use the `algorithm` environment, with style `boxed`. You'll also have a separate numbering for algorithms. As I don't have your class installed I use `article` with option `twocolumn`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{article}%,emptycopyrightspace]{ewsn-proc}%
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, balance, filecontents, graphicx, complexity, pgfplots, textcomp, tikz, tikz-3dplot}%,
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[boxed]{skip=6pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[sort,nocompress]{cite}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
 \begin{figure}[htbp]
 \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
 \textsc{SomeAlgorithm}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]

 \State Do this
 \State Do that
 \If{You cannot do this or that}
 \State Do something else
 \EndIf
 \While{You are not successful}
 \State Work hard
 \EndWhile
 \end{algorithmic} \end{minipage}}

 \caption{Some algorithm}
 \end{figure}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{algorithm}[htbp]%
    \textsc{Some Algorithm}
                \begin{algorithmic}%[1]
                    \State Do this
                    \State Do that
                    \If{You cannot do this or that}
                    \State Do something else
                    \EndIf
                    \While{You are not successful}
                    \State Work hard
                    \EndWhile
        \end{algorithmic}
    \caption{Some algorithm}
    \end{algorithm}
\lipsum[6-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]